# Swift 3 Use CoreData inside CocoaPods library

Tags: swift, core-data, cocoapods

I need to use CoreData inside my CocoaPods library. I have updated my pod specs to include the .xcdatamodeld file in resource bundle like below

```
s.resource_bundles = {
 'TestDemoPodSDK' => ['TestDemoPodSDK/Assets/*.{xib,storyboard,xcdatamodeld}']
```

}

To access the storyboard and xib files i have used the bundle resource. Is there a way to access the .xcdatamodeld file from the resource bundle ?

This is the working swift 3 code i've used to access the table

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity = TABLE_TICKET(context: managedContext)
    entity.column_RequesterName="Carey"
    entity.column_emailID = "Carey@gmail.com"

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        getData()
        print("saved user data")

    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

when i use this in CocoaPods i get undeclared type error in AppDelegate and entity creation line.

How do i get the managed context and the table entity ?

Any working examples in much appreciated..

Thanks